# Why is promise.all ([ tuti,tuti2] ) firing once?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I tried [this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-nearby-places-list-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2-part-2/) to get markers added on the map.

Everything is working fine but when I navigate to the other pages and then return to the map, page markers don’t appear. They only appear the first time.

Need help …

I’m using a menu to navigate through the pages. I tried everything even putting the method in the constructor and I tried all the functions :
`ionViewDidLoad()` ,`ionViewWillLoad()`,`ionViewDidEnter()`

…i’m helpless right now !! this is my method:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    let mapLoaded = this.maps.init(this.mapElement.nativeElement,
      this.pleaseConnect.nativeElement);
    let locationsLoaded = this.load();
    Promise.all([
      mapLoaded,
      locationsLoaded,
    ]).then((result) => {
      if(result){
        let locations = result[1];
        for(let location of locations){
          this.maps.addMarker(location);
        }
        this.maps.addMyPosition();
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Where do you use this code? In what component? If it is still visible, those life cycle methods will be called just once I think.

Comment: this method is in map page.ts and i'm using a provider "maps.ts"which contains addMarker method : " this.maps.addMarker(location);"

Comment: is there any other solution than promise ?

Comment: I have a feeling it is `this.platform.ready()` that is not completing, and not anything to do with the promises. I don't know about your debug processes, but can you check the `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{ /* check this part runs */})`

Comment: I think it should be `this.maps.addMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude);` not `this.maps.addMarker(location);`

Comment: @pandamakes i tried it without  this.platform.ready() and nothing has changed ..

Comment: @hrdkisback it works fine because location is the lat and long my problem is the code works fine but only the first time after loading the entire app

Comment: give this a shot? `ionViewWillEnter(){ console.log('ionViewWillEnter fired') }` and see if the console prints anything when you navigate back

Comment: @pandamakes yes i already did that :( everything works before the promise.all

Comment: hmm, 2 more things to try if you are game: 1) `Promise.all([ ... ]).then( ... ).catch((e:any)=>console.log(e))` <-- see if there was an uncaught error, though I highly doubt there was one, or else you should be thrown an error.

Comment: secondly:
`mapLoaded.then((result1:any)=>{console.log('result1 complete');locationsLoaded.then((result2:any)=>{console.log('result2 completed')})})` then swap them around, and see if any of the two promises are completing.

Comment: @pandamakes i tried to catch error as u said in the first suggestion and yeah it says:
       "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

Comment: clearly  `this.mapElement` or `this.pleaseConnect` is undefined. I still think it's a life cycle issue. Upon hitting Back, the @Viewchild decorator does not find the child components, and thus leaving them undfined. Without a codepen or s th to play with, it's really hard to pinpoint the actual issue. If you like, can you provide more code to your project? , e.g. how do you "navigate to other pages"?